# css assistance to draw playoff brackets

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to have a "playoff bracket" on a wordpress site page.  The brackets will be fed by database and PHP code to populate them with proper opponents and winners and losers each week.

So I am essentially trying to draw the brackets in some fashion on the page.  I am working on it here:  http://www.jerseybasketballassociation.com/1a-test-logo/

this is not perfect, just working on it; I only have the first two weeks on there…

if you do not know what I mean by "playoff bracket" you can see an example here:
http://printyourbrackets.com/8seeded.html

basically what I have is OK; but it would be much improved if I somehow was able to put some lines between the two weeks so you could see teams 1 and 8; they have lines that show the winner advancing to second week (labeled as team 1)

Does anyone have any ideas on how I would produces those lines using CSS/html?

I will also paste in the HTML and CSS code that puts this on the page:

```
<style>
#round1_boxa {border: 1px solid gray; padding: 2px; margin-bottom: 27px;}
#round1_boxb {border: 1px solid gray; padding: 2px; margin-bottom: 54px;}

#round2_boxa {border: 1px solid gray; padding: 2px; margin-top: 27px; }
#round2_boxb {border: 1px solid gray; padding: 2px; margin-top: 108px;}
#round2_boxc {border: 1px solid gray; padding: 2px; margin-top: 108px;}
#round2_boxd {border: 1px solid gray; padding: 2px; margin-top: 108px;}


#round1_cont {width: 150px; float: left;}
#round2_cont {width: 150px; float: left; margin-left: 20px;}
#game_box {margin-bottom: 30px;}
</style>
<div id="round1_cont">

<div id="game_box">
<div id="round1_boxa">
Team 1
</div>
<div id="round1_boxb">
Team 8
</div>
</div>

<div id="game_box">
<div id="round1_boxa">
Team 4
</div>
<div id="round1_boxb">
Team 5
</div>
</div>

<div id="game_box">
<div id="round1_boxa">
Team 3
</div>
<div id="round1_boxb">
Team 6
</div>
</div>
<div id="game_box">
<div id="round1_boxa">
Team 2
</div>
<div id="round1_boxb">
Team 7
</div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="round2_cont">

<div id="round2_boxa">
Team 1
</div>
<div id="round2_boxb">
Team 4
</div>
<div id="round2_boxc">
Team 2
</div>
<div id="round2_boxd">
Team 3
</div>

</div>
```

So I am trying to see if anyone has any ideas on how to draw those lines that go from box to box to delineate the advancing teams.  Thanks so much...

Comment: Have you considered using the canvas and javascript to draw that?

Comment: Hello TreeTree I guess I did not know about this canvas part of HTML, I found it on w3; looking at it; not sure what all can be done with it but I will be checking it out… thanks….

Comment: It lets you draw all kinds of primitive shapes as well as text but it all exists as one html element, the canvas. So you can't highlight or copy or whatever like you normally can.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rethink the task and change markup.

```
<div class="c1">
    <div class="team">1</div>
    <div class="team">2</div>
    <div class="team">3</div>
    <div class="team">4</div>
</div>
<div class="c2">
    <div class="block first">semi1</div>
    <div class="block">semi2</div>
</div>
<div class="c3">
    <div class="block">final</div>
</div>
<div class="c4">
    <div class="block">winner</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box}

.team {
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 40px
}
.c1, .c2, .c3, .c4 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px
}
.c1 .team {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px
}
.c2 .block, .c3 .block {
    margin-top: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    border-top: solid 2px #000;
    border-right: solid 2px #000;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #000;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.c2 .block.first {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.c3 .block {
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}

.c4 .block {
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: right;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #000;
}
```

Full example here 
http://jsfiddle.net/fncxsezn/

Comment: thanks zooman, I will be checking on this as well; this is very helpful as I needed help in "knowing" different ways to do this, so I really appreciate this in showing me what can be done… thanks...